# Power BI - ORA-01843: not a valid month

Tags: powerbi

Estou fazendo uma consulta no PBI atravez de uma View. Porém, não importa o quanto eu modifique o formato da data, ele não aceita.

A View esta abaixo:

```
select 
    NROREPRESENTANTE AS CodRepresentante, 
    nroempresa,
    seqcliente,
    skcategoria,
    count(distinct seqnf) as "Clientes Total", 
    sum(qtdoperacao) as "Produtos Vendidos", 
    sum(vlroperacao) as "Venda Total",
    sum(vlrctobruto) as "Custo Bruto",
    sum(vlroperacao*ind_promocao) as VLR_PROMOCAO,
    TO_char(DATA, 'DD/MON/YYYY') as DOPER
    from dwv_venda
where DATA between to_date('01/JAN/2018', 'DD/MON/YYYY') and 
TO_DATE('31/DEZ/2018', 'DD/MON/YYYY')
and acmcompravenda = 'S'
group by data, NROREPRESENTANTE, NROEMPRESA, seqcliente, skcategoria
order by data, NROREPRESENTANTE, NROEMPRESA, seqcliente, skcategoria
```

Já tentei `To_date` também, de varias formas. Já olhei a região no PBI, está no Brasil. Não sei mais o que faço, porque preciso determinar a range de data para reduzir as linhas que o PBI vai consultar.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed.

```
select 
  NROREPRESENTANTE AS CodRepresentante, 
  nroempresa,
  seqcliente,
  skcategoria,
  count(distinct seqnf) as "Clientes Total", 
  sum(qtdoperacao) as "Produtos Vendidos", 
  sum(vlroperacao) as "Venda Total",
  sum(vlrctobruto) as "Custo Bruto",
  sum(vlroperacao*ind_promocao) as VLR_PROMOCAO,
  data
from dwv_venda
where **to_char(data, 'yyyy') = '2018'**
and acmcompravenda = 'S'
group by data, NROREPRESENTANTE, NROEMPRESA, seqcliente, skcategoria
order by data, NROREPRESENTANTE, NROEMPRESA, seqcliente, skcategoria
```

Ele estava tendo algum problema para ler o Where de data, como eu estou separando por Ano, fiz um where mais simples e ele pegou todas as datas do ano.

:)

Comment: Seu erro original deve ter o 'DEZ' quando a configuração de nls de banco ou section estar em inglês provavelmente no caso seria 'DEC' . Uma saída seria  between to_date('01/01/2018', 'DD/MM/YYYY') and 
TO_DATE('31/12/2018', 'DD/MM/YYYY')